# Responsiveness not working correctly in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I've a page with a sidebar setup with bootstrap. When I reduce the width of the page in my browser, the sidebar goes from FULL -> COLLAPSED -> TOPBAR (meant for small screens like phones) as the width decreased

But strangely when I access this in my phone, I only see the COLLAPSED version of the sidebar whereas on that small a screen I should be seeing the TOPBAR.

I can't understand how to debug this since it works correctly in my PCs browser on reducing the width!

Any wise CSS heads here who might know what the problem might be? You can check out the sample page [here](http://fadster-dev.appspot.com/mainapp/blank).

Answer (score 1):

Please add below meta tag to recognizance device without this tag this responsive design not work in mobile : Add between <head> tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```